# Windows Explorer won't show image thumbnails when using Remote Desktop

Tags: windows-8.1, remote-desktop, windows-explorer, thumbnails

When I connect to my home `Windows 8.1` server via `RDP` (using another win 8.1 computer) and open `Explorer` to show some folder containing images, I can't get it to show the actual thumbnails, only this: [image: Generic picture instead of thumbnails of actual pictures]

Settings:

[image]

I've tested with and without `Persistent bitmap caching`

Any ideas?

Comment: What have you tried already?  For example, in the RDP connection's properties, what do you have set under the "Experience" tab?  Have you tried changing those yet?

Comment: Yes, allowing all in `Experience` didn't make any difference. I haven't been able to find anything else that affects this in the `Windows explorer`

Comment: This is abnormal. RDPing into Windows 8.1 works fine for me when showing thumbnails.  Have you tried rebooting the host computer?  Have you ensured the thumbnails show up if you're logged into it locally?  Are there any policies in lace to disable those thumbnails?

Comment: I haven't made any policy changes that I'm aware of; it's a standard win 8.1 installation. When locally logging on to the server, the thumbnails shows up as expected. This problem has existed for a long time, so the server has been rebooted many times during that. The only thing not "standard" is that I'm using OpenVPN to access the server and then open the RDP connection through the tunnel.

Answer (score 3):

Try these:
Under Control Panel > Folder Options > View > Make sure "Always show icons, never thumbnails" is unchecked.

Under Control Panel > System > Advanced > Performance > Settings > Visual Effects > make sure "Show thumbnails instead of icons" is checked.

Under Computer > right click on C:/ and click Properties > Disk Cleanup > and clear the Image Thumbnails cache

I had the same problem, and the first worked for me immediately.